# In Java, how can I grab specific lines in an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I'm just not quite sure how to properly ask this.

Let's say I have a text file with the list of:

```
name1   info   A

name2   info   B

name3   info   C

name4   info   A
```

How can I set it so that if I prompt the user for the letter (A for example), it will store the name and info of lines with letter A in a constructor?

I know how to use the `BufferedReader` and `Tokenizer` to read the lines and store them in an array list. I'm just not quite sure how to grab a specific line from that list given a single value.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Store the lines in an `ArrayList<String>` and after processing, write them back to the file with the replaced information.

Comment: is ArrayList really what you need? (Lists are ordered numberically, so you would retrieve entries by passing the index, ex: 'get item 5'.) However, I think what you need is a `Map`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html maps are sets of keys & values. It looks like you want to use the letters as the keys and the name/info as the values, ex: 'give me the values for key A'.

Comment: Or a Guava MultiMap http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html.

Comment: I've never used Map before but I'll check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're after, you could use something like this `pruneList` method

```
public static void pruneList(java.util.List<String> al, String match) {
    java.util.Iterator<String> iter = al.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().contains(match)) {
            continue;
        }
        iter.remove();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = { "name1 info A", "name2 info B", "name3 info C",
            "name4 info A" };
    java.util.List<String> al = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(
            java.util.Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println("Before pruning");
    System.out.println(al);

    pruneList(al, "A");

    System.out.println("After pruning");
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

Which outputs

```
Before pruning
[name1 info A, name2 info B, name3 info C, name4 info A]
After pruning
[name1 info A, name4 info A]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, i would pick a different format for your file, several spaces can easily be mistyped, so just stick with one space or a different char.

Here is a little example of string parsing where i use the method split to split the row on spaces and then i check for the right identifier at the end. If it matches, then i extract the data from the splitted data, and stores them in strings.

```
// You fill this list from the file, I do it here for demonstration
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("name1 info A");
list.add("name2 info B");
list.add("name3 info C");
list.add("name4 info D");

// And this identifier is read from the user
String identifier = "B";  

for (int i = 0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++) {
    String line = list.get(i);
    String[] splitted = line.split("[ ]");
    if(splitted[2].equals(identifier)){
        String name = splitted[0];
        String info = splitted[1];
        // Here you can do what you want with the data, call your constructor or     something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String userInput = "A";
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("d:\\demo.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        if(strLine.contains(userInput))
        {
             System.out.println ("The data in particular row is : "+strLine);
        }
 }
```

Comment: If u think the answer is useful then vote to increase my reputation